# How to show a button, when clicking on another button?

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick

For example, if we have btn 1 and btn 2.

Is it possible (with the onclick event) to click on btn 1, and then btn 2 appears?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**.

Any element, including `button` elements, can have events set which trigger styling properties of other elements to change.

An Example:

```js
let get = document.querySelector.bind(document),
btn1 = get("#btn1"), btn2 = get("#btn2");

btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
btn2.style.display = "initial";
});
```

```css
.hidden {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Click Me</button>

<button id="btn2" class="hidden" >I'm a button</button>
```